# Selecting rows from duplicate values, where a field never changed

Tags: mysql, sql

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Test name</th>
    <th>Result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Performance_1</td>
    <td>PASS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Performance_1</td>
    <td>FAIL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Performance_1</td>
    <td>FAIL</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Smoke_9</td>
    <td>FAIL</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Smoke_9</td>
    <td>FAIL</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

- In the above table I want to select all test cases which **never** passed once.
- It would return Smoke_9 because it has only failed, never passed.
- It would not return Performance_1 because even though it failed multiple times, it has passed once.
- It would be nice if we could SELECT * so I could inspect all fields after.

Thanks

Comment: I have tried using SELECT TestName, COUNT(*), but I could never take into consideration both FAILs and PASSes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just the `TestName`s you can `group by testname` and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select TestName
from tablename
group by TestName
having sum(Result <> 'FAIL') = 0
```

If you want all the rows for the `TestName`s that never passed, you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (select 1 from tablename where TestName = t.TestName and Result <> 'FAIL')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bec412999472e9b91a0bb03ef529f1c4).

Comment: Worked beautifully, thanks. Turns out there are no tests which failed every time haha. Double checked the opposite just in case, so the script does indeed work for future reference.